# Linq C# - Join from RAM with Database cause out of memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have join data from RAM with data in table of database

```
var dataMatched = (from ra in listInRam
                   join db in _context.TListInDB
                   on ra.DBID equals db.Id
                   select ra).ToList();
```

Table TListInDB have more 2 million record

Result: I stuck and wait at the above code line and the ram increases continuously

Comment: How many rows does your query return?

Comment: What compiler option are you using? I found compiling with 64 bit mode gets rid of some out of memory issues.  I would use task manager and verify before calling code you have a lot of memory.  Add break point before the code is executed.

Comment: If you need a `List`, all that data will be stored in memory, you could try to avoid that amount of data retrieving a subset of columns (check DaggeJ's answer) or if you are you later filtering that data you could return a `IQueryable` so when your query is executed a smaller amount of data is retrieved. Depending of what data you are storing, you may also want to insert a distinct `select des).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: I aswer all question from you guys, thank for question
How many rows does your query return? 
- 0 row

What compiler option are you using?
- VS studio 2017 comunity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. You'll get all your 2 million records into memory with the current code;

```cs
var ids = sta.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

var dataMatched = 
  _context.TBankStatements.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Statement.IdBankStatement))
     .Select(x => new PayoutMatchedPair { Transaction = ..., Matched = ... });
```

Comment: Thank your answer, however I think your solution seems confused.
I understand you want to say, but this isn't my expect answer. I founded the solution for this problem, but I want to understand workflow of linq above, and reason cause out of memory.

Is if join a list in ram with a table no condition, compiler will query all table to RAM and join after,